# Cannot run AWS Lambda using snowflake-connector

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.6, compatibility, python-3.7, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I deployed my lambda and try to run it, it generates the following error:

```
libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why? What can I do about it? I have in my requirements.txt the following.

```
snowflake-connector-python
jsonschema>=2.6.0
coverage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Supports Python3.6 runtime, while error describing "python3.7". Have you build it with python3.7 support.

P.S.
I am assuming you followed [official tutorial](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-rest-lambda.html)

Answer (score 2):

Pls follow instructions from here https://github.com/snowflakedb/examples/tree/master/lambda_function
If you run into issues, raise it there on github.

Answer (score 0):

I had built the snowflake connector with Python 3.7 (latest Alpine Linux container). When I changed container and built it with python:jessie and Python 3.6 then everything worked.